# jQuery Accordion click once expand/collapse when clicked

Tags: jquery, accordion, double-click

I've downloaded my accordion from here: http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/accordion.html and was told by my boss that he would like to have the feature open and close when the user clicks on each header.

For example, when you click on one header, it will open, and when you click on another header, that will also open but the one previously opened will not close unless the header has been clicked on again.

I was able to accomplish that by changing the code from this:

```
    animateClose: function (elem, opts) {
```

to this:

```
    animateClose: function (elem) {
```

The problem now is that the headers need to be clicked on once rather than twice. Is there a way that this can be fixed?

This is the full code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //syntax highlighter
    hljs.tabReplace = ' ';
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

    //accordion
    $('h3.accordion').accordion({
    defaultOpen: 'section1',
    cookieName: 'accordion_nav',
    speed: 'slow',
    animateOpen: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideUp with custom function
    elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
    },
    animateClose: function (elem) { //replace the standard slideDown with custom function
    elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
    }
    });
    $('h3.accordion2').accordion({
    defaultOpen: 'sample-1',
    cookieName: 'accordion2_nav',
    speed: 'slow',
    cssClose: 'accordion2-close', //class you want to assign to a closed accordion header
    cssOpen: 'accordion2-open',
    });

    //custom animation for open/close
    $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
    };

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your relevant markup as well. FYI for problems like this you may use online tools like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to submit your problematic code

Comment: From the jQuery-UI accordion [API documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Accordion): "NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an accordion.  An accordion doesn't allow more than one content panel to be open at the same time, and it takes a lot of effort to do that. If you are looking for a widget that allows more than one content panel to be open, don't use this.".  There's an example on that page of how to do multiple expanding panels in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uleloy/2/edit)**

HTML:

```
  <div class="accordion">
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
    <div>Content 1...</div>
    <h3>Title 2</h3>
    <div>Content 2...</div>  
    <h3>Title 3</h3>
    <div>Content 3...</div>  
    <h3>Title 4</h3>
    <div>Content 4...</div>  
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $accordionIO = $('.accordion h3');
$accordionIO.next('div:gt(0)').hide(); // hide all but first section

$accordionIO.click(function(){
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: This is perfect but what would I need to write if I wanted it to be initially closed?

Comment: @JoshuaWaheed just replace the second line with this line: `$accordionIO.next('div').hide();` it will hide all `div` instead of GreatherThan index. If you want a specific one to be opened you can do: `$accordionIO.next('div').hide().eq(2).show();` This will open the 3rd section by default, leaving hidden all other.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working perfectly the way I need it to.

Comment: Hi, I've added a bit of text called "Close", because I need the accordion to close when clicking on it, the same way as it would when clicking on the header. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: @JoshuaWaheed I don't want to guess where you placed that buttons. Please be more concise in asking questions, and please prepare/or/ update our demo so I can take a look

Comment: Hi, is there a code that will allow the header of this accordion to have a feature that shows a close symbol when it's open and an open symbol when it is closed? I'm also having difficulties applying many styles within the div section, is there a way of solving that?

Comment: My appologies, here's the example I've been working on, http://www.joshuawaheed.co.uk/accordion/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you read through the source file- `jquery.accordion.js`, you'll see the following code:

```
//opens a accordion panel
function open($this, opts) {
    close(opts);
    //give the proper class to the linked element
    $this.removeClass(opts.cssClose).addClass(opts.cssOpen);

    //open the element
    opts.animateOpen($this, opts);

    //do cookies if plugin available
    if (useCookies(opts)) {
        // split the cookieOpen string by ","
        id = $this.attr('id');
        setCookie(id, opts);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first thing this function does is-

```
    close(opts);
```

That is to close all opened headers. I think if you comment this line you'll achieve what you need.

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesn't make a difference. I still have to double click.